# Will using a plumbing valve in reverse to shut off water cause damage?

Tags: plumbing

Not sure why contractor installed my vanity so close to the shut off valve that I cannot turn valve clockwise. Instead of turning clockwise I have to turn anticlockwise to turn cold water off.

Will it damage the valve and leak or should I leave the way it is until a future repair is necessary?

Comment: It's not clear how turning the valve backward closes it. Please provide more detail about your plumbing, and photos if possible.

Comment: Is this a ball valve or gate valve, most ball valves won’t matter but gate valves would need to be made that way.

Comment: How many turns? Just a quarter turn, or one or more full turns?

Comment: As a side note - because the other comments suffice -- you could always remove the handle and reverse it so you don't have the interference with the wall.